# PHP - replace a string with a variable named like the string

Tags: php, variables, string

so the string is like this:

```
"bla bla bla {VARIABLE} bla bla"
```

when I use this string somewhere in a function I want to replace **{VARIABLE}** with **$variable** (or any other uppercase strings with wrapped within {} charcters). $variable (and any other variables) will be defined inside that function

Can i do this?

Comment: Yes, but this looks like a very bad idea of a template engine.

Comment: i wouldnt call it a templating engine. it's just for a small part of the site, but I want any other modules/plugins to have the ability to change the string before it gets displayed on the screen

Comment: try {GLOBALS} and you're ready to be hacked

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$TEST = 'one';
$THING = 'two';
$str = "this is {TEST} a {THING} to test";

$result = preg_replace('/\{([A-Z]+)\}/e', "$$1", $str);
```

Comment: As your solution does the trick, the /e modifier is regarded a security risk. It also exposes global variables.

Comment: I'm assuming that the input is trusted -- i.e., that the source string is coming from the original programmer and not provided dynamically from a site visitor. If that's the case, the risk is mitigated. And if it's running inside a function as stated, it won't expose any globals.

Comment: thanks. yes the string is not really dynamic. but it can be changed by other modules (scripts). these modules can have malicious code anyway, so it's not important to protect the string from them...

Comment: @bouke: You couldn't do anything malicious only using alphabetic characters. So it should be secure enough.

Comment: @nikic, what about variables like $dbuser or $dbpass? They would be disposed. On the other hand, if the code is located in a function this would be no problem because of the function's scope.

Comment: Is it possible to replace {var["key"]} by $var["key"]?

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 13):

Use a regular expression to find all substitutions, then iterate over the result and replace them. Be sure to only allow variables you would want to expose.

```
// white list of variables
$allowed_variables = array("test", "variable", "not_POST", "not_GET",); 

preg_match("#(\{([A-Z]+?)\}#", $text, $matches);

// not sure the result is in [1], do a var_dump
while($matches[1] as $variable) { 
    $variable = strtolower($variable);

    // only allow white listed variables
    if(!in_array($variable, $allowed_variables)) continue; 

    $text = str_replace("{".$match."}", $$match, $text);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Building on some of the other answers (especially Bill Karwin's & bouke)...

```
 class CurlyVariables {

  private static $_matchable = array();
  private static $_caseInsensitive = true;

  private static function var_match($matches)
  {
    $match = $matches[1];

    if (self::$_caseInsensitive) {
      $match = strtolower($match);
    }

    if (isset(self::$_matchable[$match]) && !is_array(self::$_matchable[$match])) {
      return self::$_matchable[$match];
    }

    return '';
  }

  public static function Replace($needles, $haystack, $caseInsensitive = true) {
    if (is_array($needles)) {
      self::$_matchable = $needles;
    }

    if ($caseInsensitive) {
      self::$_caseInsensitive = true;
      self::$_matchable = array_change_key_case(self::$_matchable);
    }
    else {
      self::$_caseInsensitive = false;
    }

    $out = preg_replace_callback("/{(\w+)}/", array(__CLASS__, 'var_match'), $haystack);

    self::$_matchable = array();

    return $out;
  }
}
```

Example:

```
echo CurlyVariables::Replace(array('this' => 'joe', 'that' => 'home'), '{This} goes {that}', true);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `$$vars` and `$GLOBALS` both represent security risks.  The user should be able to explicitly define the list of tags that are acceptable.

Below is the simplest single-function general solution I could devise.  I chose to use double-braces as tag delimiters, but you can modify it easily enough.

```
/**
 * replace_tags replaces tags in the source string with data from the vars map.
 * The tags are identified by being wrapped in '{{' and '}}' i.e. '{{tag}}'.
 * If a tag value is not present in the tags map, it is replaced with an empty
 * string
 * @param string $string A string containing 1 or more tags wrapped in '{{}}'
 * @param array $tags A map of key-value pairs used to replace tags
 * @param force_lower if true, converts matching tags in string via strtolower()
 *        before checking the tags map.
 * @return string The resulting string with all tags replaced.
 */
function replace_tags($string, $tags, $force_lower = false)
{
    return preg_replace_callback('/\\{\\{([^{}]+)\}\\}/',
            function($matches) use ($force_lower, $tags)
            {
                $key = $force_lower ? strtolower($matches[1]) : $matches[1];
                return array_key_exists($key, $tags) 
                    ? $tags[$key] 
                    : '';
            }
            , $string);
}
```

[edit] Added `force_lower` param

[edit] Added `force_lower` var to `use` list - Thanks to whomever started the rejected edit.

Answer (score 2):

This will work....

```
$FOO = 'Salt';
$BAR = 'Peppa';
$string = '{FOO} and {BAR}';
echo preg_replace( '/\{([A-Z]+)\}/e', "$$1", $string );
```

but it just seems like an awful idea.

Answer (score 2):

```
$data_bas = 'I am a {tag} {tag} {club} {anothertag} fan.'; // Tests

$vars = array(
  '{club}'       => 'Barcelona',
  '{tag}'        => 'sometext',
  '{anothertag}' => 'someothertext'
);

echo strtr($data_bas, $vars);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is another solution, but I agree with other folks who are dubious about whether this is a wise thing for you to do.

```
<?php

$string = "bla bla bla {VARIABLE} bla bla";
$VARIABLE = "foo";

function var_repl($matches)
{
  return $GLOBALS[$matches[1]];
}

echo preg_replace_callback("/{(\w+)}/", "var_repl", $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am glad I have found Bill Criswell's solution, but 
is it also possible to replace such variables:

string tmp = "{myClass.myVar}";

Where the PHP code would be something like:

```
class myClass
{
    public static $myVar = "some value";
}
```